# Existe alguma forma de usar Laravel Eloquent no microframework Silex?

Tags: laravel-eloquent, orm, silex

Eu estou refatorando uma estrutura de um site e passando para o microframework Silex.

Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de utilizar o ORM Eloquent do Laravel, para conectar com o banco de dados.

Eu li na documentação que tem como usar Doctrine, porém não gostei muito da ideia.

Então gostaria de saber se existe alguma biblioteca que possibilite eu usar o ORM do Laravel (Eloquent) no Silex?

Comment: https://github.com/ziadoz/silex-capsule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem como usar sim, conforme o próprio repositório [illuminate/database](https://github.com/illuminate/database), na verdade é possivel usa-lo independente de qualquer coisa, ou seja poderá usar provavelmente em qualquer framework, as únicas dependências é instalar via `composer` e ter o php5.6+, ou seja isso funcionará tanto para Silex quanto para qualquer coisa equivalente.

Digite no terminal dentro do seu projeto `composer require "illuminate/database"`, se for usar os eventos é necessário também o comando `composer require "illuminate/events"`

Ou configure o composer.json (5.4 é a versão mais atual antes da versão de desenvolvimento, pode ver outras versões):

```javascript
"illuminate/database": "~5.4",
"illuminate/events": "~5.4"
```

E depois rode o `composer update`.

Adicione o autoload.php e chame em um PHP assim:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$capsule = new Capsule;

//Exemplo mysql
$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);

// Define o dispatcher usado pelos models do Eloquent (opcional)
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

// Faz essa instancia de Capsule ficar disponível globalmente usando metodos estaticos (opcional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

// Configura o Eloquent ORM... (opcional e desnecessário se você já usou setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Essa parte acima você poderia colocar em um arquivo global o qual ficaria acessivel a todos, ou quando você chamar um namespace especifico, por exemplo `\Model\foo\bar` (falo disto depois).

Depois de incluir o arquivo acima, você pode usar:

- **QueryBuilder**

  ```php
  $users = Capsule::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->get();
  ```
- **Schema Builder**

  ```php
  Capsule::schema()->create('users', function($table)
  {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('email')->unique();
      $table->timestamps();
  });
  ```
- **Eloquent ORM** (creio que seja este que lhe interessa):

  ```php
  class User extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {}

  $users = User::where('votes', '>', 1)->get();
  ```

### Criando um namespace para usar os Models

Agora digamos que você não vai usar o ORM em todas páginas, realmente não há motivo para carregar tudo se não vai usar, então você pode querer organizar o seu projeto se baseando em um namespace, sugiro fazer algo como:

1. Crie no composer.json um namespace para apontar para uma pasta aonde ficarão os models:

   ```javascript
   ...
   "require": {
       "php": ">=5.6.4",
       "illuminate/database": "~5.4",
       "illuminate/events": "~5.4"
   },
   "autoload": {
       "psr-4": {
           "FooBarModel\\": "app/Models"
       }
   },
   ...
   ```

Esse caso é um exemplo, supondo que tenha uma pasta chamada `./app/Models` dentro do projeto.

2. Você pode criar um Model abstrato que será a base de tudo em `./app/Models/Model.php`, assim evitará de incluir o Eloquent em chamadas que não vai usar o banco (claro que isso é só uma maneira de organizar)

   Neste caso você deve remover do arquivo global tudo o que citei antes deixando lá somente o `require`:

   ```php
   <?php

   namespace FooBarModel;

   use \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
   use \Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
   use \Illuminate\Container\Container;

   $capsule = new Capsule;

   $capsule->addConnection([
       'driver'    => 'mysql',
       'host'      => 'localhost',
       'database'  => 'database',
       'username'  => 'root',
       'password'  => 'password',
       'charset'   => 'utf8',
       'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
       'prefix'    => '',
   ]);

   $capsule->setAsGlobal();

   $capsule->bootEloquent();

   //Cria a classe
   abstract class Model extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {}
   ```
3. Então agora na mesma pasta você pode criar um Model chamado `User` (`./app/Models/User.php`):

   ```php
   <?php

   namespace FooBarModel;

   class User extends Model {}
   ```

   Se estiver em uma sub-pasta (`./app/Models/Admin/FooBar.php`):

   ```php
   <?php

   namespace FooBarModel\Admin;

   class FooBar extends \FooBarModel\Model {}
   ```
4. Crie o tal global.php (ou qualquer coisa assim) que possua o `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`, ou se tiver um boot.php ou no seu index.php da vida jogue lá, supondo:

   ```
   <?php

   require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
   ```
5. Então para chamar um Model especifico, por fazer assim:

   ```
   <?php

   require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

   $user = new FooBarModel\User\User;
   ```
6. Um exemplo com Silex pode ser assim:

   ```php
   <?php

   use FooBarModel\User;
   use FooBarModel\Admin\FooBar;

   require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

   $app = new Silex\Application();

   $app->get('/', function ()
   {
       return 'Home';
   });

   $app->get('/user', function ()
   {
       $user = new User;
       ....
   });

   $app->get('/user', function ()
   {
       $user = new FooBar;
       ....
   });

   $app->run();
   ```